# How can I install a git post-receive hook if I don't have server-side access to the repository?

Tags: git, notifications, githooks, slack

A service I'm using ([Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com)) offers a git repository interface. I'd like to install a post-receive hook so that when my collaborators and I commit changes to the repository, we'll get notifications in [Slack](https://slack.com). Normally, this could be done easily using, e.g., Chris Eldredge's [git-slack-hook](https://github.com/chriseldredge/git-slack-hook), but it requires installing the post-receive hook on the server. In the current case, I don't have direct access to the git repository server's file system.  I've tried creating `.git/hooks/post-receive` in my local copy, but `git` won't let me check it in:

```
# git add .git/hooks/post-receive 
error: Invalid path '.git/hooks/post-receive'
error: unable to add .git/hooks/post-receive to index
fatal: adding files failed
```

What is the proper procedure for installing a post-receive hook when you can't directly access the file system of the git repository server?

Note: this is *not* GitHub.

Comment: A local cron that does a git remote update, then git status/git show-branch master -pass the details through to slack?

Answer (score 1):

I always track my Overleaf projects locally and sync from local to github. You can add github integrations from your github project to the desired slack channels as described in

https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201824286-Setting-up-the-GitHub-app

There are links to using github organisations and to reducing the permissions required by slack on that page.

One could automate this with say cron pulling from Overleaf to local, then pushing to Github. I have not looked for a cloud based solution to syncing, but presumably it could be achieved, removing the need for local syncing. It would then work when you were not online which could be important, say in a group of more than two.

Note that you will get all updates made on Overleaf, even if a Version tag was not added. This will result in the un-helpful commit message, "Update on Overleaf". I don't yet have a non-manual solution for this problem, as I don't automate my own system.

An alternative to using Overleaf is to use the SageMath Cloud (I don't have sufficient reputation to post the link). This approach is somewhat more technical, and I have collaborators who do not want to deal with it, so it may not be suitable for you. On the other hand, you get a full terminal, access to computational tools and can manage your work in a git repository just as you would locally. Then just sync with github after commiting and the slack integration will take care of the rest.

Either method would benefit from a post commit hook to automatically push to github on commits, such as can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/stinoga/3136312

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the server or a service that overcome this for letting you add a git hook, it seems that there is no way for you to solve this.
Overleaf seems a hosting for collaboration of documents that is controlled totally by them so you won't get any access for putting git hooks. It is also looks that their service is build for non-git users and they just added a git API so you can access you files as git-repository.
The best solution for you is to ask Overleaf support directly for a solution for you or to switch to a 'real' git hosting service.